# How can I disable highlightSpans for one slide in a xaringan presentation

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan

In an R Markdown/xaringan document I am using `highlightSpans: true` to highlight text throughout a presentation:

```
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: ["default"]
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightLines: true
      highlightSpans: true
```

I have one slide that has code that I would like to show as is (wihtout causing the backticks to trigger highlighting):

```
I did a lot of work and the p-value was `r round(results[[5]][1], 2)` and this made me sad.
```

How can I tell rmarkdown/xaringan to set the `highlightSpans:` option to be `false` for one slide?